# Python timedelta update is randomly subtracting 2 days

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta, pytz

My program has 2 `datetime` objects, one is present, another one is `updated_at`, which it gets via api. The goal is simple, compare them and show how long ago it's been updated.

```py
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import pytz

frontier_tz = pytz.timezone('UTC')
frontier_time = datetime.now(frontier_tz)

...
updated_at = '2020-05-07T07:16:39.000Z' # this value is provided by an api
updated_at = frontier_tz.localize(datetime.strptime(updated_at[0:16], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M'))
# since it's a string, it has to be converted into a datetime object
updated_ago = frontier_time - updated_at
updated_ago_text = str(updated_ago).split(':')[0]
# the result is something like "1 day, 2", then I add surrounding text
```

This last piece of code updates resulting text with a loop every 30 minutes, where it gets new data from api and compares present time and `updated_at`.

Here's the problem: at random it will subtract 2 days from `updated_ago` and become negative in most cases, since most objects are being updated daily.

I've tried debugging it and adding 2 days in case the result is negative:

```py
if updated_ago < timedelta(seconds=0):
    print('ALERT!', updated_ago)
    updated_ago += timedelta(days=2)
    print(updated_ago)
    updated_ago += timedelta(days=-2)
```

And the result is even more frustrating. It took me several days of testing (since this bug appears at random). For example, let's say that `updated_ago` is "1 hour". When 2 days are being added, `updated_ago` suddenly un-bugs, adds 2 days to the correct value and becomes "2 days, 1 hour", and if 2 days are being subtracted again, it subtracts them from a correct value of "1 hour" and becomes "-2 days, 23 hours".

Here's the printout of latest instance of this bug:

```
ALERT! -1 day, 23:54:04.378389
1 day, 23:54:04.378389
```

Comment: Please provide sample data that clearly exhibits the problem - see how to create a [mcve]

Comment: @ThierryLathuille added the variable. I can also provide in-between values as well if necessary.

Comment: since we don't have access to the API: are you sure these timestamps are valid? In general, it would be much easier if it would give you a posix timestamp in seconds since the epoch (just in case that is an option).

Comment: also, the string '2020-05-07T07:16:39.000Z' is already localized if you parse it as `datetime.strptime(updated_at, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')`

Comment: @MrFuppes yes, I have checked data that comes from API, it is valid. That was actually the first thing I've checked. And also, this interpretation doesn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: One more thing that came to my mind why this could go wrong is that the timestamp you get from the API is not always UTC - since you cut the tz info in the string, this *could* happen. However, such API behavior would not make much sense in the first place...

Comment: @MrFuppes I've checked data validity in many cases of this bug, every time it's solid. If you take a look at the "if" part of my original post, you'll see it's not working properly at all. Adding 2 days actually adds 4 for some reason.

Comment: note: a timedelta '-1 day, 23:54:04.378389' means one day before, at 23:54:04.378389 (check the `total_seconds()`). so if you add 2 days, you will get +1 day,  at 23:54:04.378389. that seems all correct...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213321/discussion-between-gleb-ivanov-and-mrfuppes).

Answer (score 1):

As weird as this bug is, the solution is even more bizarre. Works for my case, since resulting value higher than 24 hours is extremely unlikely but might not work in other cases:

```py
if updated_ago < timedelta(seconds=0):
    updated_ago += timedelta(days=1)
    updated_ago = timedelta(days=1) - updated_ago
```

I've tried out many different variants that make more (and sometimes less) sense than this one yet this one seems to do the job.
If anyone else stumbles upon such bug, please leave a comment because it seems this is a python `datetime` library bug.